# Why is my right Iframe not showing in iPad devices?

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, iframe

I am testing my website on an Ipad. It works perfectly find on a regular desktop computer. But when testing it on an iPad the right frame is not showing... Here is a screenshot of how it is supposed to look

[image]

Here is how it looks on an ipad

[image]

Here is the code I am using to load up both frames in the index page

```
<iframe src='baseMenu.php' width='65%'  name='menu' id='menu' title='Menu Frame' ></iframe><iframe src='orderStart.php' width='35%' name='menu-item' id='menu-item'   title='Menu Items Frame'></iframe>
```

Not sure why this is happening. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `iframe` was deprecated. And is there any special reason you are using an `iframe` for `.php` files?

Comment: deprecated by who/when?